# How to change a batch file to let user enter a new string before looping again after 30 seconds?

Tags: batch-file

I'm hoping someone can help me add a function to the batch script we use at my photo studio.

Currently I have a script that first asks you to enter your Log in, then press enter. It then prompts for what Process Class you want your files to have added at the end of the file name. (Process Class is something we use in the studio like `PC_620`, it appends it to the end of the file name right before the .jpg). However, you then press enter and for the rest of the time your shooting, it applies `.PC_620` or what ever one you chose, until you close the program. It cycles through every 30 seconds sweeping the folders for new files, but during the 30 second countdown at the end, before it cycles again, you can press ANY KEY to go ahead and restart the cycle.

Currently if you want to change your Process Class, you have to exit the script, reopen it, then select the new process class.

Can I set it up so at the end of the cycle, during the 30 second countdown, you could hit a specific key on the keyboard which would reset the script so you could change your Process Class without shutting it down?

Even if it fully reset the thing it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but if I understood it correct, you could use `timeout` (available from windows Vista) command to count down. You could use this command and loop it to ask for the input again.

```
D:\>timeout /?

TIMEOUT [/T] timeout [/NOBREAK]

Description:
    This utility accepts a timeout parameter to wait for the specified
    time period (in seconds) or until any key is pressed. It also
    accepts a parameter to ignore the key press.

Parameter List:
    /T        timeout       Specifies the number of seconds to wait.
                            Valid range is -1 to 99999 seconds.

    /NOBREAK                Ignore key presses and wait specified time.

    /?                      Displays this help message.

NOTE: A timeout value of -1 means to wait indefinitely for a key press.

Examples:
    TIMEOUT /?
    TIMEOUT /T 10
    TIMEOUT /T 300 /NOBREAK
    TIMEOUT /T -1
```

Cheers, G

Comment: I know it was a confusing question, i wasn't sure how to word it, Let me try again.

Comment: @ECHO OFF
color 9A
  set /p username=ENTER LOGIN:

  echo.
  echo.

   :pc

 echo   1 -- Flats
 echo   2 -- Simple Tabletop
        
 set /P rmFunc="Enter a choice: "
 for %%I in (1 x) do if #%rmFunc%==#%%I goto run%%I
 
 :run1
 set pc=300
 goto begin
 
 :run2
 set pc=400
 goto begin

  :begin
  set studio=TT
                set computer=Handbag_1
  set setnumber=
  set studiosetnumber=%studio%_%setnumber%
  set delay_swch=5
                set delay_loop=30

                :bottom

echo logged in as: %username%

  timeout /t %delay_loop%
  GOTO BOTTOM